# Can`t push to remote repository when known_hosts is not empty

Tags: git, ssh

I`m tring to push local brach to remote using IDEA bundled Git integration plugin.
When it start pushing I can see in Version Control Console windows something like this

```
git push origin <local_brach_name>:<remote_branch_name>
```

Idea show new task named "Pushing" but nothing happen.
After that I open known_hosts file and clean it. Now if repeat push action IDEA will show modal dialog with offer to add new setting to known_hosts file.
After adding that push action finishing in a few moments.
But next push action will not work again.

Added string is different every time

If push using Git Bash problem will be the same. Pushing action for a very long - cancel it - clean known_hosts - repeat push - console offer to add new host - push finished OK.

Any ideas?
Should I change something in git configuration? Can it be connected to some network issues?

Update:
Windows 7 64, IDEA 12.0.3, Git Bash 1.8.0-preview20121022, GIT_SSH is undefined in my enviroment

Comment: What git version are you using? On what OS are you in (Mac? Unix? Windows?), what version of IDEA and of Git Plugin are you using? What is the value of the environment variable GIT_SSH?

Comment: This seems like an `ssh` problem rather than git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a connection trouble. Now I have better connection and the trouble is gone.